# Dockerhub: listing all available versions of a given image?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm looking for a way to list all publicly available versions of an image from Dockerhub. Is there a way this could be achieved?

Specifically, I'm interested in the `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` images.

Dockerhub typically only lists the latest version of each image, and there are no linking to historic versions. For [`openjdk`](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk), it's currently `8u191-jdk-alpine3.8`:

[image: Dockerhub openjdk alpine]

However, it possible to pull older versions if we know their image digest ID:

```
openjdk:8-jdk-alpine@sha256:1fd5a77d82536c88486e526da26ae79b6cd8a14006eb3da3a25eb8d2d682ccd6
openjdk:8-jdk-alpine@sha256:c5c705b462abab858066d412b3f871865684d8f837571c98b68e78c505dc7549
```

With some luck, I was able to find these digests for OpenJDK 8 (Java versions 1.8.0_171 and 1.8.0_151 respectively), by googling `openjdk8 alpine digest` and looking at github tickets, which included the image digest.

But, is there a systematic way for listing all publicly available digests?

Looking at `docker search` documentation, there's doesn't seem to be an option for listing the image version, only search by name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need digests to pull "old" images, you would rather use their tags (even if they are not displayed in Docker Hub).

#### EDIT (2023/10/01): with Docker Hub v2 API, because v1 has been deprecated

Docker Hub v1 API [has been deprecated on 2022/09/05](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-hub-v1-api-deprecation/), so we now need to use [the v2 API](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest/).

Use the following command to retrieve tags of a particular image, parsing the output of `https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/$REGISTRY/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags`. You also need `jq` installed to parse JSON result:

```bash
# for official images, REGISTRY is library and REPOSITORY is the name of the image
# otherwise, split the image name (e.g. google/cloud-sdk into REGISTRY=google and REPOSITORY=cloud-sdk)
REGISTRY=library
REPOSITORY=openjdk

next_page="https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/$REGISTRY/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags?page=1&page_size=1000"

while [ "$next_page" != "null" ]
do
    result=$(curl -s "$next_page")
    echo $result | jq -r '.results[].name'
    
    next_page=$(echo $result | jq -r '.next')
done
```

Unlike with v1 API, we need to paginate here (so we use the `next_page` value to get all results).

You can then filter and only keep tags you're interested in, with `| jq 'select(match("^19.*jdk-alpine"))'` or `| grep -E '^19.*jdk-alpine'`.

Result for `REGISTRY=`library `REPOSITORY=openjdk` (11812 tags at the time of writing) looks like:

```
22-slim-bullseye
22-slim-bookworm
22-slim
22-oraclelinux8
22-oraclelinux7
22-oracle
22-jdk-slim-bullseye
22-jdk-slim-bookworm
22-jdk-slim
22-jdk-oraclelinux8
[...]
```

#### Old answer using Docker Hub v1 API (won't work anymore, API is now deprecated)

I use the following command to retrieve tags of a particular image, parsing the output of `https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags` :

```
REPOSITORY=openjdk # can be "<registry>/<image_name>" ("google/cloud-sdk" for example)
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags -O - | \
    jq -r '.[].name'
```

Result for `REPOSITORY=openjdk` (1593 tags at the time of writing) looks like :

```
latest
10
10-ea
10-ea-32
10-ea-32-experimental
10-ea-32-jdk
10-ea-32-jdk-experimental
10-ea-32-jdk-slim
10-ea-32-jdk-slim-experimental
10-ea-32-jre
[...]
```

If you can't/don't want to install [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (tool to manipulate JSON), then you could use :

```
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags -O - | \
    sed -e 's/[][]//g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ //g' | \
    tr '}' '\n'  | \
    awk -F: '{print $3}'
```

(I'm pretty sure I got this command from another question, but I can't find where)

You can of course filter the output of this command and keep only tags you're interested in :

```
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags -O - | \
    jq -r '.[].name | select(match("^8.*jdk-alpine"))'
```

or :

```
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags -O - | \
    jq -r '.[].name' \
    grep -E '^8.*jdk-alpine'
```